# Why aren't my parameters getting passed through to a dispatched event?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, addeventlistener

I've set up an event listener like this...

```
window.addEventListener('message', parseMessage, false);

var parseMessage = function(rawMessage) {
    console.log(rawMessage.cmd);
};
```

And then I'm triggering the event like this:

```
var event = new Event('message', {'cmd':"blerg!"});

window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

The problem is the console.log in parse message is logging out undefined when I am expecting to to log out "blerg!"

What I am I doing wrong here with the events, how to I pass the 'cmd' message through to the event?

Comment: You should use `CustomEvent`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FEvents%2FCreating_and_triggering_events#Adding_custom_data_.E2.80.93_CustomEvent

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. Use [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FEvents%2FCreating_and_triggering_events#Adding_custom_data_.E2.80.93_CustomEvent) **instead** of `Event` for creating custom events.
2. Specify your data in a 'details' object (see code).
3. I changed the event name because `message` is also used for the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage). It didn't cause problems when running in Chrome, but I wouldn't use it.

```
var parseMessage = function(rawMessage) {
  console.log(rawMessage);
  console.log(rawMessage.detail.cmd);
};

// changed event name
window.addEventListener('myMessage', parseMessage, false);

// data should be in a 'details' object
var evt = new CustomEvent('myMessage', {
    detail: {
      'cmd' : "blerg!"
    }
});

window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Here is an adjustment for IE >= 9 compatiblity (using [`document.createEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CustomEvent::initCustomEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
var evt = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
evt.initCustomEvent('myMessage', false, false, {
    'cmd': "blerg!"
});
```

Comment: That's brilliant thanks, just wondering, does it have to be inside an json called 'detail' or is that something you've added?

Comment: @Smickie Your custom data has to live in the 'detail' key. It doesn't work otherwise. (Btw, it isn't called a 'json'. 'detail' is a so-called "key").

Comment: Nice answer. Btw, Object Literal is the term your looking for `typeof ({detail:{cmd:'blerg!'}}).detail` ;-)

Comment: Might be worth adding that you can use Modernizr to detect if CustomEvent is supported then you can choose which approach to use to create your event.

Comment: See MDN Polyfill in the answer of @olefrank

Answer (score 27):

For IE9/10 polyfill you can use this code provided by Mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

```js
(function () {
  if (
      typeof window.CustomEvent === "function" ||
      // In Safari, typeof CustomEvent == 'object' but it otherwise works fine
      this.CustomEvent.toString().indexOf('CustomEventConstructor')>-1
  ) { return; }

  function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
    params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
    var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
   }

  CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

  window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
})();
```

Also described here but with wrong URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22946340/1736012

Comment: This also fixes it in IE11

Comment: Its not only fixing IE9/10 but IE11 as well ;)

Comment: Thanks for this fix

Comment: I've also had to add the line `window.Event = CustomEvent;` for IE11, to allow for supporting code like `new Event("myEvent")`