# CustomEvent() constructor is not supportive in IE

Tags: javascript, html

The `CustomEvent()` constructor is not supported in IE. Is it possible to make it compatible with IE11 at least? It's working with other browsers like Chrome and Firefox.

ex:-

```
var SpecialEvent = new CustomEvent(
  "SpecialMessage",
  {
   detail:
   {
     message: "Hello There",
     time: new Date()
   },
   bubbles: true,
   cancelable: true
  });
```

Comment: How about reading what [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says about it? Why [Java] tag?

Comment: remove superfluous tag

Answer (score 1):

MDN provides a polyfill for IE >= 9. See below.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

```
(function () {

  if ( typeof window.CustomEvent === "function" ) return false;

  function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
    params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
    var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
   }

  CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

  window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
})();
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

This should work on IE9+

```js
var SpecialEvent = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
SpecialEvent.initCustomEvent('SpecialMessage', false, false, {
  detail: {
    message: "Hello There",
    time: new Date()
  },
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
});
```

Picked up from here.. [Why aren't my parameters getting passed through to a dispatched event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345392/why-arent-my-parameters-getting-passed-through-to-a-dispatched-event/19345563#19345563)

Answer (score 0):

Use less time and energy and save yourself future hardships by switching over to jQuery events rather then using some special prototype sauce to get IE to work.  jQuery events have a better implementation and are compatible with IE.

[unless you are firing events across frames then you need to prototype and use the traditional `window.dispatchEvent(evt)` ]

Old way:

```
var SpecialEvent = new CustomEvent(
  "SpecialMessage",
  {
   detail:
   {
     message: "Hello There",
     time: new Date()
   },
   bubbles: true,
   cancelable: true
  });
```

New way:

```
$(window).trigger("SpecialMessage", ["Hello There", new Date()]);
```

And to catch that event:

```
$(window).on("SpecialMessage",function(e, arg1, arg2){
    console.log(arg1);   // Hello There
    console.log(arg2);   // 2018-04-18...
});
```