# Webpack "production" mode is causing an exception in IE11

Tags: webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, webpack-4

I am bundling my TypeScript application with Webpack 4, and compiling with Babel. When using `mode: "production"` in `"webpack": "^4.42.1",` I get the error `Unhandled promise rejection Typeerror: Object doesn’t support this action` in IE11. The error doesn't occur in any other browsers, and it doesn't occur when using "developement" or "none" mode. Because the other modes are working, I assume that the error is due to a "production" mode configuration, and not (directly) related to my babel config. My guess is that some "production" config is not playing nice with Babel.

I wonder if there are any known reasons why "development" would be IE11 compatible, but "production" would not. I have been trying to reverse-engineer the issue by using the same `production` config found [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/#mode-production) with `mode: "none"` to try and produce the same error. Once the issue can be re-produced without `mode: "production"`, it should be straightforward to deduce the culprit option. So far I have not had any success. The snippet provided does not contain the `TerserPlugin` config, and for all I know might not actually be a 1:1 match of "production" mode.

Comment: Please share a minimum example of that code that triggers the problem

Comment: I can share my webpack and babel config, but the error does not produce a line number that I can use to pinpoint a trigger unfortuantely. That's part of the reason this issue has been so hard to debug.

Comment: See this plugin [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) should help

Comment: The error message means that `Promise` itself has been polyfilled but you passed it the wrong kind of content. It's hard to locate the issue with only the description. Are there any steps to reproduce the issue? Besides, you could refer to the [Browser Compatibility](https://v4.webpack.js.org/concepts/#browser-compatibility) part of Webpack to see if you need to load a polyfill.

Comment: I did some more debugging and narrow it down to `CustomEvent` being the issue. The weird part is that I have a [polyfill in place for this already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345392/why-arent-my-parameters-getting-passed-through-to-a-dispatched-event/31783177#31783177). For some reason, this polyfill is not working correctly in "production" mode, I currently suspect it is an issue with the Webpack terser.

I have an ongoing issue for the problem with Webpack: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10675

Comment: If the issue is with terser then you could try to disable it as a workaround. Try to set `optimization.minimize` to `false` [like this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationminimize). I suggest you can also report to [terser team](https://github.com/terser/terser/issues) about this issue. Besides, you could also try to use [`custom-event-polyfill`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-event-polyfill) to polyfill `CustomEvent` in IE 11.